# Standardisation of usage of "..." (ellipsis)

Tags: punctuation, ellipses

Normally, ellipsis uses three consecutive dots with no space between the dots and the preceding word.

But, at places, I find the ellipsis used in various manners:

> 1. "He is fond of..." (Three dots with no space between the dots and the preceding word.)
> 2. "He is fond of ..." (Three dots with a space between the dots and the preceding word.)
> 3. "He is fond of...." (Four or more dots with no space between the dots and the preceding word.)
> 4. "He is fond of ...." (Four or more dots with a space between the dots and the preceding word.)

To me, usage of ellipsis is standardised: it must have three consecutive dots with no space between the  dots and the preceding word.

Is the usage of ellipsis going through a further evolution? Has the usage of ellipsis been actually standardised? What is the correct rule of using ellipsis? Which of the above uses is/ are correct?

Comment: [Two dots is not an ellipsis](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60452). Four dots means the ellipsis coincides with a period/full stop (as at the end of a sentence). Otherwise, the presentation of the ellipsis is a matter of style. Not only are there variations of spaces and no spaces, but some use half-width spaces. See e.g. *[What is the proper way of using triple dots and spaces before/after them?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26240)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the proper way of using triple dots and spaces before/after them?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26240/what-is-the-proper-way-of-using-triple-dots-and-spaces-before-after-them)