# I'm trying to quote a point in the text and I want to skip to another part, how would i do this?

Tags: writing, quotes, quoting

I would like to quote something and then add another point in the text for example:

> first part
>
> [other stuff]
>
> second part

I would like to be able to use *first part* and then *second part* in the same quote without using the filler in the middle, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This ultimately depends on your style guide, although it will be usually some type of ellipsis that you will need to use. The major American style guides that I checked all use ellipses with spaces next to each period(`. . .`).

From the [APA Blog](https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2015/05/punctuation-junction-quotation-marks-and-ellipses.html):

> In APA Style, double quotation marks are used to enclose
>   quoted material, and an ellipsis is a set of three spaced periods used to show that material has been omitted from a quotation.

The [Perdue OWL](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_formatting_quotations.html) specifies that MLA is the same:

> If you omit a word or words from a quotation, you should indicate the deleted word or words by using ellipses, which are three periods ( . . . ) preceded and followed by a space.

And CMOS too, from the site [CMOS Shop Talk](https://cmosshoptalk.com/2018/11/20/ellipses-with-periods-cmos-13-53/):

> When words are left out of a quotation, an ellipsis of three dots (. . .) takes their place. When this works correctly, the reader can skip over the dots and the sentence continues smoothly on the other side.

. . .

> Chicago style puts a space between ellipsis dots. A period before an ellipsis closes up to the preceding word as usual, but a space comes between the period and the ellipsis.

Comment: You aren't distinguishing what one should type on a typewriter versus how one should typeset this—and these are quite different! For one, the typesetter has many widths of spaces available to them, but the primitive typewriter only one. For another, you must guarantee that no line-break occurs before or within these dots. Finally, there can be no right answer that fails to account for the nature of whichever typeface is used: not merely the size it’s to be set at, but also whether it uses light open letterforms or heavy closed ones. [See Bringhurst](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/91654).